# Alter Column Datatype from Int to Ntext and vice-versa

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [UserTable]
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In this table the ID column has the datatype `int`. I want to alter the data type of the ID column to `Ntext`.

For that I am using the following Sql Query:

```
ALTER TABLE UserTable
ALTER COLUMN ID NTEXT
```

This query gives the following error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with ntext

While when I alter ID column Datatype from **Int to navarchar** it works fine.

After that I am trying to Alter **ID**(now the data type of the Id column is Nvarchar) Column data type to **Ntext** by **Alter Query** it alters **ID** column data type successfully.

Why can't we alter column data type directly Int to Ntext, while we can do this via INT to Nvarchar after that Nvarchar to Ntext?

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated in favour of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and shouldn't be used for new work. Why on earth would you want to convert an `int` column to `ntext` anyway?

Comment: @Martin: there is no any specific reason,I am just trying to do this for testing purpose and I got the error message,So want to know about the error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do an implicit conversion which is [disallowed from int to ntext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Why, I don't know, but I guess because it's 2 steps (int->string, string->LOB).

Also, don't use ntext. It's deprecated. Use nvarchar(max) which should allow implicit conversion.

Finally, if ID is the primary key then why do want a LOB type? You *do* have a primary key...?

Comment: @GNB:I am not using it in real application I just test something, thanks